# styling the optional input fields

Tags: css, html, validation

I have a web form where some input fields are required and some are optional. I can give style the required fields as I expect but can't the optional ones.

When the optional fields have a valid input it will turn green(for instance). And it works with this code

```
input:optional:valid{
background: #AAB69B
}
```

But generally like as first loading they will be in another color. For this, I am trying this code

```
input:optional{
background: #f19999 
}
```

But this doesn't work. I can't select the optional fields when they have no input. Unfortunately, with no input value they get the background as I set for the valid input. When I start typing , it get my expected invalid background. And when the input gets valid, the field gets valid background (it works).

Please, help !

Demo Link : http://bdlance.byethost9.com/front-end%20form%20validation%20with%20html5/

Comment: That code should work - http://jsfiddle.net/am9d9mr4/1/ Can you make a demo of it **not** working.

Comment: @Paulie_D  , here is the domo http://bdlance.byethost9.com/front-end%20form%20validation%20with%20html5/

Answer (score -1):

Taking a look at your form styles, I've seen that your background color is similar for both `valid` and `invalid` pseudo classes:

```
input:required:invalid, textarea:required:invalid{
    background: #AAB69B; // same
}
input:required:focus:invalid, textarea:focus:invalid{
    background: #AAB69B; // same
}
input:required:valid, textarea:required:valid{
    background: #AAB69B; // same
}
input:optional, select {
    background: #f19999;
}
input:optional:valid{
    background: #AAB69B; // same
}
```

Try this instead:

```
input:required:invalid, textarea:required:invalid{
    background: #f19999;
}
input:required:focus:invalid, textarea:focus:invalid{
    background: #f19999;
}
input:required:valid, textarea:required:valid{
    background: #AAB69B;
}
input:optional, select {
    background: #f19999;
}
input:optional:valid{
    background: #AAB69B;
}
```

Sorry, but your CSS file is not the best, Please do dedicate more time to learn CSS. Here are some good resources (the order matters):

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS
- https://flukeout.github.io/
- https://smacss.com/
- https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/